# Need shell script group by with adding count with unique field

Tags: shell, sh

Eg :-

```
cat exception.txt

5 tomcatexception
2 URL exception
3 timeout exception
2 tomcatexception
1 URL exception
```

Result Should come as below;

```
7 tomcatexception
3 URL exception
3 timeout exception
```

Comment: your output numbers 7, 3, 3 dont make sense. You want the sum of column 1 or the count?

Answer (score 1):

Code:

```
awk '{c=$1;$1="";e[$0]+=c;}END{ for (key in e){print e[key] key}}' exception.txt
```

In body of awk script create array with keys equals to rows (without count of exceptions first column) 
$1="" // removes first column from row so $0 is equal to name of exception and become KEY in array
e[$0]+=c // sums values from first column with same key (exception name)

in the END of awk use loop through all elements in array and print its value and its key.

Comment: While this code may answer the question, explaining *how* it solves the problem would improve the usefulness and long-term value of the answer.